# Function to find all occurrences of substring

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x

This function returns a list of all the beginning indices of a substring in a string. After finding the index of a substring, the search for the next one begins just after this index.

```
def find_substring(substring, string):
    """ 
    Returns list of indices where substring begins in string

    >>> find_substring('me', "The cat says meow, meow")
    [13, 19]
    """
    indices = []
    index = -1  # Begin at -1 so index + 1 is 0
    while True:
        # Find next index of substring, by starting search from index + 1
        index = string.find(substring, index + 1)
        if index == -1:  
            break  # All occurrences have been found
        indices.append(index)
    return indices
```

Comment: This seems quite reasonable when you are not super-concerned with performance and are searching for small patterns.  Otherwise, it's best to go to more advanced algorithms like [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html) or [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).  These work by preprocessing the search pattern, so you can use results from previous search failures to skip searching from several positions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would turn this function into a generator so that an iteration over its values does not unnecessarily build a list into memory. If the caller trully needs a list, they can still call `list(find_substring(...))`. I would also rename this function `substring_indexes` as I feel it better convey what this function is about; also `index` could be something like `last_known_position` or `last_found`. But naming is hard and I might be wrong on this one.

```
def substring_indexes(substring, string):
    """ 
    Generate indices of where substring begins in string

    >>> list(find_substring('me', "The cat says meow, meow"))
    [13, 19]
    """
    last_found = -1  # Begin at -1 so the next position to search from is 0
    while True:
        # Find next index of substring, by starting after its last known position
        last_found = string.find(substring, last_found + 1)
        if last_found == -1:  
            break  # All occurrences have been found
        yield last_found
```

Answer (score 4):

The example in the docstring should illustrate that the returned indexes may overlap, since that is not apparent from the function name, and since other `find_all` functions behave differently.

Also, don't mix single and double quotes unless you have good reason. The example should therefore be

```
substring_indexes("ana", "Canadian banana")
```

Comment: I got the idea to mix the single and double quotes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python. The top answer used single quotes for single words, and double quotes for sentences.

Comment: Ah, ok. But still, both the string and the substring are then of the same category, therefore I think they should use the same quotes. After reading that answer, I switched to using double quotes, thanks for the hint.